# Thread Modes Problems setting password for exiting user in Ion Auth

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, ion-auth

I have problems setting password for exiting user in Ion Auth, Version: 2.5.2, Codeigniter : 3.1.0-dev

In application/config/ion_auth.php I have by default :

```
$config['hash_method']    = 'bcrypt';   // sha1 or bcrypt,  bcrypt is STRONGLY recommended
$config['default_rounds'] = 8;      // This does not apply if random_rounds is set to true
$config['random_rounds']  = FALSE;
$config['min_rounds']     = 5;
$config['max_rounds']     = 9;
$config['salt_prefix']    = '$2y$';

$config['default_group']              = 'Members';           // Default group, use name
$config['admin_group']                = 'Admin';             // Default administrators group, use name
$config['identity']                   = 'email';             // A database column which is used to login with
$config['min_password_length']        = 6;                   // Minimum Required Length of Password
$config['max_password_length']        = 20;                  // Maximum Allowed Length of Password
$config['email_activation']           = FALSE;               // Email Activation for registration
$config['manual_activation']          = FALSE;               // Manual Activation for registration
$config['remember_users']             = TRUE;                // Allow users to be remembered and enable auto-login
//$config['user_expire']                = 986500;               // How long to remember the user (seconds). Set to zero for no expiration
$config['user_expire']                = 0;               // How long to remember the user (seconds). Set to zero for no expiration
$config['user_extend_on_login']       = TRUE;               // Extend the users cookies every time they auto-login
$config['track_login_attempts']       = FALSE;               // Track the number of failed login attempts for each user or ip.
$config['track_login_ip_address']     = TRUE;                // Track login attempts by IP Address, if FALSE will track based on identity. (Default: TRUE)
$config['maximum_login_attempts']     = 3;                   // The maximum number of failed login attempts.
$config['lockout_time']               = 600;                 // The number of seconds to lockout an account due to exceeded attempts
$config['forgot_password_expiration'] = 0;                   // The number of milliseconds after which a forgot password request will expire. If
```

In my control I run :

```
    $OkResult = $this->ion_auth_model->reset_password($lUserOperator['email'], $GeneratePassword) ;
    AppUtils::deb($OkResult, '$OkResult::');
```

where `$GeneratePassword` is string like `'JKC3vmci'`, `$lUserOperator['email']` is valid email of active user, value of returned value `OkResult` = 1

looking into db for updated user I see password value like `'$2y$08$vyeSO30G4eQL3efuYbNii.VAlayDrAslKQNMDkdLYegggcsLWsQbe'` and salt field is `empty string(not NULL)`. But I can not login to system, but I login under usual login ok. What can be the reason of problem?

Also revieing code of ion_auth I see in `reset_password` function triggering events like `post_change_password`, `post_change_password`...

Could you please give ref to examples of using of this events?

Answer (score 1):

> In my control I run :

```
$OkResult = $this->ion_auth_model->reset_password(...
```

Why are you calling the `ion_auth_model` directly?

This is unnecessary and likely the cause of your troubles since you're bypassing much of Ion Auth's critical logic.

As per [the developer's documentation](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#ci2_compatibility):

> **NOTE**: Methods available in the model are called through the controller using PHP5 magic. You should **never use `ion_auth_model->method()` in your applications**.

---

The developer has already provided many relevant functions you can use anywhere in your project.  To update any user's account including resetting their password, you would use [the `update()` class](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#update)...

```
$id = 12; // <- Existing user's ID
$data = array(
    'password' => '123456789',  // <- NEW password
);
$this->ion_auth->update($id, $data); // <- Update the user's account
```

`update()` returns `true` if the update was successful and `false` if not.

If you don't know the user's `id`, then you simply do a standard database query on the `"users"` table to retrieve their `id` based on email address.

> Could you please give ref to examples of using of this events?

See documenation:  [benedmunds.com/ion_auth](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth)